# Why can't I use SelectLayerByAttribute_management while a cursor is set

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I've been having a problem with arcpy in that the simple line:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("TEMP_LINES")
```

produces this response: Runtime error : ERROR 000358: Invalid expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

I've worked out that this error only occurs when a cursor is set, like this:

```
lineCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("TEMP_LINES","","","combined_i")
```

Can I not use select by attribute and the cursor or do I have one of them set up wrong?

EDIT: whole code:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (Lines,"TEMP_LINES")

lineCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("TEMP_LINES","","","combined_i")

for row in lineCursor:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("TEMP_LINES")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management (Polygons, "INTERSECT", "TEMP_LINES")
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (Polygons, "temp_polys")
    polyCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("temp_polys")
    blocks_list = []
    for row in cursor:
        blocks_list.append(row.getValue("BLOCK"))
    blocks_str = ', '.join(blocks_list)
    lineCursor.BLOCK = blocks_str
```

Comment: You don't provide a valid expression for the Select Layer by Attribute GP tool. You only provide the layer name which is not enough.

Comment: without the cursor on this selects all. It doesnt work with any expression with the cursor on

Comment: Can you provide the whole chunk of code you execute please? I am a bit confused in which sequence you have those rows.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I've edited to include

Comment: i've tested your code succefully, without any problems, it seems that the problem is not located in `SelectLayerByAttribute_management `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by others you have not provided a selection criteria for `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()`. Additionally  using `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` within an Update Cursor is only going to apply to a single row and does not really make sense to do.

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, I think you need to rework your logic in this script. Perhaps run the `arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management()` previous to creating your cursors and use a `where_clause` as an argument to your `arcpy.UpdateCursor` to limit the number of records that you are searching and updating against.

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectLayerByAttribute_management` tool in your script is trying to select all features within the feature layer, whereas the cursor accesses one row at a time within the feature.  If you would still like to use the tool within the cursor then there is a bit of an adjustment needed.  I should make mention that this adjustment assumes the field `"combined_i"` is not unique.

```
lineCursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("TEMP_LINES","","","combined_i; unique_field")
cols = arcpy.ListFields("TEMP_LINES")

for row in lineCursor:
    for col in cols:
        if col.name == "unique_field":
            objstr = row.getValue(col.name)
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("TEMP_LINES", "NEW_SELECTION", ("%s = %s" % (col.name, objstr)))
    .
    .
    .
```

Allow me to explain the additional code in more detail:

```
cols = arcpy.ListFields("TEMP_LINES")
    for col in cols:
        if col.name == "unique_field":
            objstr = row.getValue(col.name)
```

First, list all fields in `"TEMP_LINES"`, then loop through the fields and find a field named `"unique_field"`.  If true then set `objstr` equal to the value of "unique_field" in the current row.

```
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("TEMP_LINES", "NEW_SELECTION", ("%s = %s" % (col.name, objstr)))
```

Instead of trying to select all features in `"TEMP_LINES"` this will only select the feature with the unique value in `"unique_field"` at the current row.